# Double Join to get data from a table based on other two tables

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have three tables with the following key fields:

```
CONTRACTS
    reference
    package

EVENTS
    reference
    condition1
    condition2

TRADES
    reference
    event_reference
```

Basically, what I would like to do is the following:

1. Get all the `reference` of the table `EVENTS` where the two conditions (`condition1` and `condition2`) are met;
2. Hence, getting all the `reference` of the table `TRADES` where `TRADES.event_reference = EVENTS.reference`
3. Finally, getting the `CONTRACTS.package` where the `CONTRACTS.reference = TRADES.reference` (after having filtered the data at the point 2).

In order to do this, I have tried a `JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT CONTRACTS.package
FROM CONTRACTS
JOIN TRADES ON CONTRACTS.reference = TRADES.reference
JOIN EVENTS ON TRADES.event_reference = EVENTS.reference
WHERE EVENTS.condition1 = '1.511' AND EVENTS.condition2 IN (1,2)
```

However, the above (which is executed without errors) does not issue any result, and I would actually expect to see some. 
I hence understand that I'm being wrong in the logic that I follow: could anyone please help?

**EDIT**: this is an example of how the data look like (in yellow, I have highlighted the data that would be touched in the query if it was working as I had it in mind:

[image]

...here is the expected result:

```
1 (package of 4, related to 11 which satisfies condition 1 and 2)
2 (package of 6, related to 13 which satisfies condition 1 and 2)
4 (package of 10, related to 16 which satisfies condition 1 and 2)
```

and here are the data to copy-paste them:

```
CONTRACTS   
reference   package
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   2
6   2
7   3
8   3
9   4
10  4
```

---

```
EVENTS      
reference   condition1  condition2
10  1.511   0
11  1.511   1
12  1.202   0
13  1.511   2
14  1.511   0
15  1.202   0
16  1.511   1
```

---

```
TRADES  
reference   event_reference
2   10
4   11
5   12
6   13
7   14
9   15
10  16
```

Comment: Can you include some sample data?

Comment: Sure, let me prepare them and add to the question.

Comment: You could try a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6fab/3) I know isnt sybase, but choose the one closest to your rdbms

Comment: At first your query looks ok, so my guess is the data doesnt match your desire result.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza updated, sorry but I'm a bit under pressure, it takes me too long for the moment preparing a fiddle :)

Comment: Which Sybase DB are you running?

Comment: Hello @frlan, it's a Sybase ASE 11/12/15 - TDS 5.5

Comment: what is the datatype of `condition1` and `condition2`?

Comment: @vkp that was a simplification, the real condition is the following: `WHERE EVENTS.condition1 = '1.511' AND EVENTS.condition2 IN (1,2)`, where `condition1` is a `string` and `condition2` is an integer that can be `0`, `1` or `2`.

Comment: please edit the sample data to show the values for condition1 and condition2 as well

Comment: @vkp, sure, it's done, don't hesitate to tell me if something is still unclear.

Comment: i can't see an error. the query you have should return the expected result.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c23b56/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks OK

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b94b/3)**

```
SELECT CONTRACTS.package
FROM CONTRACTS
JOIN TRADES ON CONTRACTS.reference = TRADES.reference
JOIN EVENTS ON TRADES.event_reference = EVENTS.reference
WHERE EVENTS.condition1 = 'true' AND EVENTS.condition2 = 'true'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| package |
|---------|
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       4 |
```

Comment: Well, in the end it was all due to the equivocal field names (having the same name, but referring to different things). Technically this question is useless for future users (since it doesn't fix any problem), I will let it just for sample purposes and not to make you lose the rep you deserved for the effort you did on double-checking :)